# How to update appium 1.1.0 beta

Tags: android, appium, python-appium

I need to update the latest version of the appium, alas, in the Russian forums there is not much information for it. I have a 1.1.0 beta

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the appium command line tool,then you can update to the desired version by using below mentioned command:

npm update -g appium

If you want to install version 1.6.3 :

Command : npm install appium  1.6.3

Also,if you want to update through appium UI,then you can update by clicking on 'Check for Updates' button available under 'File' menu.